# How do I add an entry to a custom object array

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing a CSV file into a PScustomobject array, with 4 columns and need to add entries to the object further along in the script.

When I try to do this and put the data in columns, I get the pleasant response of Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "4".

A simplified version of the code:

```
 $Localadmins = import-csv "c:\admins.csv"
    $LocalAdmins

    Scope  Admin      Server    Type      
    -----  -----      ------    ----      
    Domain John.Smith SRV-SQL01 LocalAdmin
    Local  svc_sql    SRV-SQL01 LocalAdmin

    $LocalAdmins.Add("Domain", "Frank.Zappa", "SRV-SQL01", "LocalAdmin")

> Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "4".
> 
> At line:1 char:16
```

Comment: Piping your variable (`$LocalAdmins`) to `Get-Member` or gm for short, would show you the methods available on that object. As you can see by the error, it doesn't have an 'Add' method which is why your code isn't working.

Comment: Shouldn't your second line be     `$localadmins` (one word)

Comment: Thank you both, Itchydon - yes it was a typo that I have fixed. Robin - I can see you are correct in what you are saying. this identifies the root cause (which is great), but didn't get me a fix. still helpful in expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with:

```
 $Localadmins = import-csv "c:\admins.csv"
 $newRow = New-Object PsObject -Property @{ Scope  = 'Domain' ; Admin = 'Frank.Zappa'; Server 0 'SRV-SQL01'; Type = 'LocalAdmin' }
 $Localadmins += $newRow
```

So you've to create a new `PsObject` and add it via the `+=` operator.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you, explanations in the comments. Feel free to paste it in the PowerShell ISE so you can see what happens while debugging it.

```
# Simulate $Localadmins = import-csv "c:\admins.csv" $Local Admins
$Localadmins = @"
Scope, Admin, Server, Type
Domain, Frank.Zappa, SRV-SQL01, LocalAdmin
Domain, Led-Zeppelin, SRV-02, LocalAdmin
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# See what is possible with the object
# Notice there is no 'Add' method available

$Localadmins | Get-Member

<#
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition                     
----        ----------   ----------                     
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj) 
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()              
GetType     Method       type GetType()                 
ToString    Method       string ToString()              
Admin       NoteProperty System.String Admin=Frank.Zappa
Scope       NoteProperty System.String Scope=Domain     
Server      NoteProperty System.String Server=SRV-SQL01 
Type        NoteProperty System.String Type=LocalAdmin 
#>

# Add one user
$Localadmins += [PSCustomObject]@{
    Scope = 'Domain'
    Admin = 'Chuck-Norris'
    Server = 'MyServer'
    Type = 'LocalAdmin'
}

# Add another group of users by using an array
# and adding that array to the original one

$ExtraArray = @"
Scope, Admin, Server, Type
Domain, UserA, PC01, LocalAdmin
Domain, UserB, PC02, LocalAdmin
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Localadmins += $ExtraArray

$Localadmins
```

Comment: I can see what you mean and understand the fix. Thank you.